# Incoherent orientation ov UIViewController and StatusBar when using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, orientation, screen-orientation

I've some UITabBarController. In landscape I hide tabBar and expand contents view. Code looks like this:

```c
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  UIView *transView = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
      transView.frame = self.view.bounds;
      self.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    } else {
      self.tabBar.hidden = NO;
      CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
      frame.size.height = self.tabBar.frame.origin.y;
      transView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

This handles orientation changes without problem.

Problem appeared when I've added usage of `UIImagePicker`. `UIImagePicker` enforces portrait orientation when it is shown (Apple breaks own UI rules: do not enforce orientation).
When application is in landscape and `UIImagePicker` is shown `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is invoked twice and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)` returns `YES`.
So far so good.
Now when `UIImagePicker` is closed (by picking a photo or cancel), `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is invoked once and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)` returns `YES`, so it should be ok, but result looks like this:
[image: Screen shot]

As can be seen status bar is in landscape (ok), UI is in portrait (fail): ui is show as in portrait, also `UIController` left a space for status bar (black stripe on left), UI is also clipped at top by status bar.

Now this looks like a iOS bug, since `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)` returns `YES` but UI remains in portrait.

Environment: iOS 6.1.3 iPod Touch 5g.

Is there a way to fix it: make status bar remain on left xor enforce UI in landscape?

---

**Update**:
after further investigation I've noticed that `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` are never called during this scenario. I even added this log in various places and it always prints "3 3 3 3" (`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`):

```
NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d",
      self.navigationController.interfaceOrientation, 
      self.interfaceOrientation, 
      self.selectedViewController.interfaceOrientation, 
      [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation);
```

So state information says `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` but I see portrait UI and landscape status bar.

---

I've added this kind of logs to see when rotation is performed:

```
  UIView *view = self.view;
  int i=0;
  while(view) {
    CGAffineTransform trans = view.transform;
    NSLog(@"Transform: %d %@", i, NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(trans));
    ++i;
    view = view.superview;
  }
```

In case of normal rotation (from portrait to landscape) log looks like this:

```
Transform: 0 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 1 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 2 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 3 [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
Transform: 4 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

In problematic case: device in landscape, closing `UIImagePicker`:

```
Transform: 0 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 1 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 2 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 3 [1, 0, -0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 4 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Transform: 5 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

This is strange that view stack has changed (increased by 1). Also it can be seen that view with index `3` is problematic.

Comment: Did you try this? [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

Comment: I tried to invoke it from `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`. The result is that immediately after closing `UIImagePicker` it is ok, but after about 0.2 second status bar returns to problematic state :/. Flipping the UI would be better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found EVIL HACK on this mysterious issue:

```
- (void)doAWorkaroudnOnUnwantedRotation {
  // check if is workaround nesesery:
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      UIViewController *fake = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
      UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
      [rootController presentModalViewController: fake animated: NO];
      [fake dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    });
  }
}
```

I call this method when `UIImagePicker` is dismissed. Without `dispatch_after` nothing happens since picker is animated and until animation finishes this workaround will not work.